# Monotouch binding Objective c Class Extension / Categories

Tags: objective-c, xamarin.ios

I am trying to bind my first 3th party library to my monotouch project. Most of the binding works, but I am having trouble with binding Objective C Class Extensions. I am aware of the part "Binding Class Extensions" in the [Binding Objective-C Types](http://docs.xamarin.com/ios/Guides/Advanced_Topics/Binding_Objective-C_Libraries) document, but unfortunately it didn't help me out.

these are the 2 extension I am trying to bind:

```
// category on UIViewController to provide access to the viewDeckController in the 
// contained viewcontrollers, a la UINavigationController.
@interface UIViewController (UIViewDeckItem) 

@property(nonatomic,readonly,retain) IIViewDeckController *viewDeckController; 

@end

// category on WrappedController to provide access to the viewDeckController in the 
// contained viewcontrollers, a la UINavigationController.
@interface UIViewController (WrapControllerItem) 

@property(nonatomic,readonly,assign) WrapController *wrapController; 

@end
```

And this is the way I am trying to bind them:

```
[BaseType (typeof(UIResponder))]
interface UIViewController
{
    [Export ("viewDeckController", ArgumentSemantic.Retain)]
    IIViewDeckController ViewDeckController { get; set; }

    [Export ("wrapController", ArgumentSemantic.Assign)]
    WrapController WrapController { get; set; }
}
```

And then when I am trying to compile this in my application:

public partial class AgendaView : UIViewController

I am getting the following error:

'UIViewController' is an ambiguous reference between 'MonoTouch.UIKit.UIViewController' and 'ViewDeck.UIViewController'

I've tried to search the web for a solution for this but I couldn't find it, so I would be pleased if anyone could help me any further.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Any luck Guido with this one? I think I am stucked on the same third party library mapping :-(

Comment: Trying to do the same thing, any luck guys?

Comment: Hi guys, sorry late response.. but I got stuck on this. I finally found some other component that was written in C# that I could use. But I believe Xamarin made it easier right to do this see link: [Objective Sharpie](http://blog.xamarin.com/introducing-objective-sharpie/?mkt_tok=3RkMMJWWfF9wsRonv6jJZKXonjHpfsX54%2BQpXqC%2BlMI/0ER3fOvrPUfGjI4ASsJjI%2BSLDwEYGJlv6SgFQ7fAMapvwrgKXRg%3D)

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to specify the namespace.
Either explicit:

```
public partial class AgendaView : MonoTouch.UIKit.UIViewController
public partial class AgendaView : MyBindingsNamespace.UIViewController
```

or by `using`:

```
using MyBindingsNamespace;
public partial class AgendaView : UIViewController
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for you reply. But that's not the solution because: 
- when I use MonoTouch.UIKit.UIViewController then my property ViewDeckController is not available for my AgendaView.
- when I use ViewDeck.UIViewController then all methods from the MonoTouch.UIKit.UIViewController are not available..

So I want the property ViewDeckController { get; set; } to be an extension of the UIViewController class.